# How to set stack_size, stack_addr and guardsize when creating a thread

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I'm reading [APUE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) these days, and just found an issue.

One common way to use `pthread_attr_setstack` is to

1. `malloc` a chuck of memory
2. set the `addr` and `length` by the method

Then, here comes my question, what if I want to use the guard-size to protect my data? Say I need `A` bytes of memory, and `B` bytes for guard-size.

Shall I `malloc` `A+B` bytes, or `malloc` `A` bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually pthread library itself provides an API to [set the guard size](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setguardsize)

```
int pthread_attr_setguardsize(pthread_attr_t *attr, size_t guardsize);
```

But note that if you are setting the stack location or size, either using functions like  [`pthread_attr_setstack(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstack) or [`pthread_attr_setstackaddr(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstackaddr), which you are, then the guard size attribute is ignored (i.e., no guard area is created by the system): it is the your responsibility to handle stack overflow (perhaps by using [`mprotect(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) to manually define a guard area at the end of the stack that you have allocated.

So, coming to your specific question, yes, you need to malloc `A+B` bytes to include the guard area yourself if you wish to use `pthread_attr_setstack`. Else, if you are OK with the default stack size, then you use the `pthread_attr_setstack` function.

Read about [`pthreads`](http://www.cognitus.net/html/howto/pthreadSemiFAQ_5.html) here. Also read specifically about thread stack management [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) under the section `Stack Management`